# redirection from one url to another url without any interconnection

Tags: angularjs, url, window

HTML:

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="initiatePayment();">Proceed to pay</button>
```

Credit Controller.Js:

```
$scope.intitiatePayment = function(){
    $scope.redirect = response.json.response.data.links;
    $window.location.href = $scope.redirect[i].href;

}
```

I have payment gateway integration , now when i click on proceed to pay button I open the link in given by backend after successful payment , it will redirect to JSP page configured by backend and now I wanted it to be auto closed after 5 seconds and redirect to my page. 
Is it possible to handle it via client side.

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout to call the close function. in close function open your page which you want

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout){


$scope.intitiatePayment = function(){
    $scope.redirect = response.json.response.data.links;
    $window.location.href = $scope.redirect[i].href;
    $timeout( function(){
           $scope.close();
        }, 5000 );

}
$scope.close = function(){
// call your page here 
}
})
```

**Note :** Include $timeout option in your controller